# Proper way to overload argument types in Python functions

Tags: python, types, arguments

Loosely following the guideliene "return the most specific type, accept the most generic type", I'll often have functions that accept arguments of multiple types.

For example, if we want to accept a filepath, generally we're okay with accepting a string or a `Path` instance. Typically I handle this with something like:

```py
import pathlib

def do_something(fpath: pathlib.Path | str):
    if isinstance(fpath, str):
        fpath = pathlib.Path(fpath)

    new_file_path = fpath / "new_file.csv"
    # do more ...
```

Is this best practice? Is there a proper way to handle "overloading" argument types like this? Are there any relevent docs I can read through?

Comment: Check out `typing.overload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it is fine to use the isinstance check, since the function argument can be either a string or a Path. But do consider what might happen if a user passes in a bytes object, or a custom class that supports the / operator. Your function would fail in these cases, despite the user's expectations.

A way to avoid this is to rely on exceptions: try to use the object as a Path, and if it fails, handle the exception.

```
def do_something(fpath: pathlib.Path | str):
    try:
        new_file_path = fpath / "new_file.csv"
    except TypeError:
        fpath = pathlib.Path(fpath)
        new_file_path = fpath / "new_file.csv"
    # do more ...
```

This way, you're not checking for specific types, and any object that supports the / operation will work.You can also write a decorator that does this type conversion for you, which would be more Pythonic and flexible.

```
def ensure_path(func):
    def wrapper(fpath: pathlib.Path | str, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(fpath, str):
            fpath = pathlib.Path(fpath)
        return func(fpath, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@ensure_path
def do_something(fpath: pathlib.Path):
    new_file_path = fpath / "new_file.csv"
    # do more ...
```

Here, the decorator ensure_path wraps the function and converts fpath to a Path object if it's a string. The do_something function only needs to handle Path objects.

Comment: This makes sense! Am I wrong to treat the type hints as a binding contract (that will break if a user passes any other arg type)? Maybe it's not pythonic to assume/prescribe argument types